# Do I need to include dependent static library of a static library into my program

Tags: dependencies, static-libraries

I have a static library which I used into my program. This static library also depends on some static library. To run my program I also need put these dependent static libraries into my project working directory.

Now, my question is it possible to have only one static library instead of giving all the dependent static libraries into my project working directory?

Is it must to give all the dependent static libraries that I used into my own static library to run my program?

Thanks in advance.
Sorry for my poor English.